# how to make pivot in this situation

Tags: sql

I don't know to to describe this problem but just look at the table and result I want to have.

TABLE:

| name | login | permissions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john doe | joedoe | read |
| john doe | joedoe | modify |
| john doe | joedoe | delete |
| jane doe | janedoe | read |
| jane doe | janedoe | modify |

RESULT I WANT

| name | login | read | modify | delete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john doe | joedoe | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| jane doe | janedoe | 1 | 1 | 0 |

My table which on I'm working is quite bigger. Here's query:

```
with cte
     as (
     select name, login, permissions
from table
join ... many tables and statements
where is_active = 1)
select name, login,
case when exists (select 1 from table where permissions like '%read%')
then 1 else 0 end as 'read'
from cte
```

The main problem is every column have 1 like everyone has permissions but it's not true.

Answer (score 0):

You need case statements, you can do something like

```
SELECT 
name, 
login, 
SUM(CASE WHEN permissions = 'read' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS read,
SUM(CASE WHEN permissions = 'modify' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS modify,
SUM(CASE WHEN permissions = 'delete' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS deleted
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work if u have more than 1 table?

Comment: Case _expressions_...

Comment: Product specific answer to a questions with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: microsoft server ssms